# How to handle azure web job pending restart

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am currently using azure web job using queue trigger , so whenever there is message in queue , I invoke a function which will do time consuming task ( pushing data to document DB ) of 15 min  and am able to do as well, now am getting socket exception du to my azure app plan and web start is restarting on its own and again this function is retried multiple times before it go poison queue.

couple of things I would like to know

1. How to handle the exception and do some logging ?
2. How to delete the existing message in queue before the web job start again so that we are not doing concurrent operations ?
3. Is there any event that will be fired before web job shuts down so that I can do anything

appreciate any help or pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to handle the exception and do some logging ?

To handle exceptions in WebJob, you could add try-catch in your WebJob and put all the Job code in the try block.

Another way to do it is using [ErrorTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#errortrigger), we need to install 
﻿Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions before using it.

> How to delete the existing message in queue before the web job start again so that we are not doing concurrent operations ?

You could change the MaxDequeueCount property to 1. If a exception happens, the message will move to poison queue immediately.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```

> Is there any event that will be fired before web job shuts down so that I can do anything

I haven't found any event which will be fired before web job shuts down. There are 2 things which will cause web job shuts down.

1. Exception occurs, we could log the exception using try-catch block or ErrorTrigger.
2. Web job aborted due to Web App Plan restarted. We could add a CancellationToken typed parameter to the function,  the IsCancellationRequested property will be set to true before the WebJob aborted due to Web App Plan restarted.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage2([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.Run(new Action(LongRunningTask), cancellationToken);
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The function has been Cancelled");
        }
    }
}

public static void LongRunningTask()
{

}
```

The Output will be like this before the WebJob aborted.

```
[06/12/2017 01:55:38 > 9d3635: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[06/12/2017 01:55:42 > 9d3635: INFO] The function has been Cancelled
[06/12/2017 01:55:43 > 9d3635: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[06/12/2017 01:55:43 > 9d3635: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
```